# How to make face_recognition get right face number?

Tags: python-3.x, face-recognition

Please download the image and save it as `test.png`.

[image: download and save it as test.png]

Everyone can see that there are two person in it,each one has a whole face.
Let python code count the face number in the image.

```
from PIL import Image
import face_recognition
image = face_recognition.load_image_file('test.png')
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)
print("I found {} face(s) in this photograph.".format(len(face_locations)))
```

Output :

```
I found 1 face(s) in this photograph.
```

How to make face_recognition get right face number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image, number_of_times_to_upsample=2, model="cnn")
```

It will work longer but more accurate then default "hog" model and the only one upsample run.

Comment: I've tried your picture with my own app... and got the same result: the only single face recignition. The reason is low quakity of that particular picture, small and rotated faces.